# C error within function returning malloc?

Tags: c, function, memory, dynamic, malloc

I was given a piece of code in C, and the question asked about it is whats wrong with it? I would be fine answering, but the asterisk in front of the malloc casting is confusing the heck out of me!

```
char f() { return *(char*)malloc(10); }
```

Comment: IMHO, that asterisk is the thing wrong with that function.

Comment: Hint: the `*` is dereferencing the pointer returned by `malloc`.

Comment: Yeah, but i need to elaborate it, like what's it doing to the whole code. And code will compile just fine even with the asterisk there...

Comment: "i need to elaborate it": What does that mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function returns an indeterminate value and has a memory leak because the dynamically allocated memory is not freed.

Comment: Oooh yeah, that piece of allocation will never be able to get freed. I was losing my mind because everything is okay with the code, since malloc returns pointer to void, its casted to char pointer and then dereferenced to unknown value. I never even crossed my mind that it will lose the adress of allocated block and therefor it cant be deallocated!

Thanks a ton friend!

Comment: "*returns an indeterminate value*" I'd say it even more provokes UB when used to assign "something": `char ch = f();`

Comment: @alk According to the C Standard (6.2.6.1 General) "5....If the stored value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is undefined." However in this example there is used an expression of type char.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with this code:

- The return value of `malloc` is dereferenced without checking if it is NULL.  So if `malloc` fails, this will result in a NULL pointer dereference and will likely cause a core dump.
- Assuming `malloc` succeeds, the memory it returns is not initialized to anything.  The function dereferences the pointer and returns the first byte in the allocated memory, which again is uninitialized.  This means the function is returning an uninitialized character.
- The pointer returned by `malloc` is not saved anywhere.  This results in a memory leak.